# How to flip artboards in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, file-placing

At a time when I try to open my *.ai file, I have a message:

[image: The file "New.ai" was generated by a newer version og Illustrator. Would you like to import this file? Some data loss may occur.]

I click <kbd>ok</kbd>.

And than I see this:

[image: Select the page from the PDF to open.]

I click <kbd>ok</kbd> and just one artboard is opening. But I need all 7 artboards. How to flip between them after opening? Or, how to open all artboards at once?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. If it allows you to import one page at a time only, then you could copy and paste that page into a new document with 7 artboards. Then open the file again, select the next page, copy and paste, and repeat until done.

Comment: You can place 7 different pages into one document

Comment: @billy-kerr, thank you, I think that's a good decision.

Comment: @joojaa, thank you, it is my only option today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update to Adobe CC, otherwise your older version (is that CS6?) can only open this in single page mode. This is why you are getting one page instead of 7.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no place to update it.  Am I to understand that it is impossible without updating?

Comment: Probably impossible yeah.